# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

This is the error I receive when I debug the app, I don't understand why this happen. I'm trying to parse the exercise and when the "for" pass again trow this error.

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.

WinRT information: The name already exists in the tree: %0.

Additional information: Unspecified error

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

XAML:

```
<RichTextBlock x:Name="rchSpecialPagesLlenaBlanco"  Foreground="Black" Margin="50,0,0,0" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False"/>
```

Code:

```
case 2:
      rchSpecialPagesLlenaBlanco.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      rchSpecialPagesLlenaBlanco.DataContext = tmpExcersice.LlenaBlancoExcersiceList.ElementAt(0);
      rchSpecialPagesLlenaBlanco.Blocks.Clear();
        for (int x = 0; x < tmpExcersice.LlenaBlancoExcersiceList.Count(); x++)
                {
                    rchSpecialPagesLlenaBlanco.Blocks.Add(parser.ParseParaCrecer(tmpExcersice.LlenaBlancoExcersiceList.ElementAt(x).ExcersiceNumber, MyBookMetadata.Course, currentFontSize, Colors.Black, new FontFamily("Resources/Fonts/Programa Tutorias Bold.ttf#Programa Tutorias")));
                    rchSpecialPagesLlenaBlanco.Blocks.Add(parser.ParseParaCrecer(tmpExcersice.LlenaBlancoExcersiceList.ElementAt(x).ExerciseText, MyBookMetadata.Course, currentFontSize, Colors.Black, new FontFamily("Resources/Fonts/Programa Tutorias Bold.ttf#Programa Tutorias")));

                }
                break;
```

Comment: The error message seems quite specific you're adding a name that already exists.  Put in check to see if the tree already contains the name you want to add.

Comment: I just adding the three exercise I put in the xml.

Comment: The amount doesn't matter.  It could be only 2 but if they both have the same name you'll get the same error when you try to add the second one.